# Does AES (128 or 256) encryption expand the data? If so, by how much?

Tags: encryption, compression, aes

I would like to add AES encryption to a software product, but am concerned by increasing the size of the data. I am guessing that the data does increase in size, and then I'll have to add a compression algorithm to compensate.

Comment: Given the point of encryption is to add entropy, I expect compression would have little effect. Though, you could try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

AES does not expand data. Moreover, the output will not generally be compressible; if you intend to compress your data, do so before encrypting it.

However, note that AES encryption is usually combined with [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29), which *will* increase the size of the data (though only by a few bytes).

Comment: Also mind that besides padding usually the cryptodata requires a CipherBlockmode which requires an IV ("initialisation value") and to be secure a MAC algorithm to protect against modification. For AES and most block modes the IV is 16 bytes and the most common HMAC (Sha1) is another 16 bytes.

Answer (score 28):

AES does not expand the data, except for a few bytes of padding at the end of the last block.

The resulting data are not compressible, at any rate, because they are basically random - no dictionary-based algorithm is able to effectively compress them. A best practice is to compress the data first, then encrypt them.

Comment: Note that the few padding bytes will be added even if the input is an even multiple of the cipher's block size; there needs to be *some* padding so that the unpadding code can work out how much padding there is.

Answer (score 13):

It is common to compress data before encrypting. Compressing it afterwards doesn't work, because AES encrypted data appears random (as for any good cipher, apart from any headers and whatnot).

However, compression can introduce side-channel attacks in some contexts, so you must analyse your own use. Such attacks have recently been reported against encrypted VOIP: the gist is that different syllables create characteristic variations in bitrate when compressed with VBR, because some sounds compress better than others. Some (or all) syllables may therefore be recoverable with sufficient analysis, since the data is transmitted at the rate it is generated. The fix is to either to use (less efficient) CBR compression, or to use a buffer to transmit at constant rate regardless of the data rate coming out of the encoder (increasing latency).

AES turns 16 byte input blocks into 16 byte output blocks. The only expansion is to round the data up to a whole number of blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the VoIP attack example. This is a nightmare to think being compromised like that.

Answer (score 5):

I am fairly sure AES encryption adds nothing to the data being encrypted, since that would give away information about the state variables, and that is a Bad Thing when it comes to cryptography.

If you want to mix compression and encryption, do them in that order. The reason is encrypted data (ideally) looks like totally random data, and compression algorithms will end up making the data bigger, due to its inability to actually compress any of it and overhead of book keeping that comes with any compressed file format.

Answer (score 0):

If compression is necessary do it before you encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

No. The only change will be a small amount of padding to align the data to the size of a block

However, if you are compressing the content note that you should do this *before* encrypting.  Encrypted data should generally be indistinguishable from random data, which means that it will not compress.

Answer (score 0):

@freespace and others: One of the things I remember from my cryptography classes is that you should not compress your data before encryption, because some repeatable chunks of compressed stream (like section headers for example) may make it easier to crack your encryption.

Comment: If your algorithm is that vulnerable to a known plaintext attack, you're probably screwed regardless. There are just as predictable cribs in many structured format commonly transferred. Most modern systems are designed to operate in modes that prevent such attacks being feasible.

Comment: Correct!  the compressed data will often have fewer repeating or guessable segments than actual plaintext. Suppose you are encrypting a Java code file.  Will anyone guess that // appears often?  Also: Zip vendors compress before encrypting.

Comment: @Cheese Sounds like something a random IV should take care of.

Comment: Many years later @Kasprzol has been proven correct. CRIME and BREACH vulnerabilities.